# ASP.NET Duplicating entries when added to several rows

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to add same entry to multiple rows.
My project contains table **Store** and table **Tag**. It's a many-to-many relationship; each store can contain several tags, and each tag can be related to several store.

**Store.cs:**

```
public class Store{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

**Tag.cs**:

```
public class Tag{
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Tags are posted separately then related to stores in PUT request.

**StoreController.cs**:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutStore(int id, StoreViewModel model){
         var store = await db.Stores.FindAsync(id);
          if (model.tags != null)
                {
                    foreach (var modelTag in model.tags)
                    {
                        var databaseTag = db.Tags.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == modelTag.Name);
                        if (databaseTag == null)
                            store.Tags.Add(new Tag()
                            {
                                Name = modelTag.Name
                            });
                        else
                            if (!store.Tags.Any(sc => sc.Name == modelTag.Name))
                                store.Tags.Add(databaseTag);
                    }

                    foreach (var storeTag in store.Tags.ToList())
                        if (!model.tags.Any(s => s.Name == storeTag.Name))
                            store.Tags.Remove(storeTag);
                }
}
```

StoreViewModel contains an array of tags.
So why are the tags being duplicated rather than linked to different stores?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you actually update the Database before calling PutStore a second time? There is also a race condition when PutStore is called from different threads at the same time

Comment: Yes i do, I call `db.Entry(store).State = EntityState.Modified;

                await db.SaveChangesAsync();`